# Get IP of incoming client - TCP - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, ip, client

I'm triyng to get the IP of an incoming client connection request :

```
1_ My computer scan all the IP in my network
2_ When it find a valid IP , it send to it a connection request 
3_ The destination computer will have to get the IP of the client that is sending a connection request and create a 
   New TcpListener(ClientTriyngToConnectIP,64535)
```

**So theres a way to get the IP of a client trying to connect to my computer ?**

Comment: That is not how TcpListener works.

Answer (score -1):

Finally i found a solution : this can be implemented in an application to get the IP  of another computer trying to connect to your via TCP

To initialize the tcp listener :

```
 Private InputClient As TcpClient
 Public ConnectionRequestListener As TcpListener

 Public sub Listener(IncomingPort as String)

 Dim IPv4_Address As String = ""

 For Each address In Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
        If address.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            IPv4_Address &= address.ToString
            Exit For
        End If
 Next

    ConnectionRequestListener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(IPv4_Address), IncomingPort)
    ConnectionRequestListener.Start()

end sub
```

Accept client :

```
InputClient = ConnectionRequestListener.AcceptTcpClient()
```

To get the IP of the client :

```
IPAddress.Parse((CType(ConnectionRequestListener.RemoteEndpoint,IPEndPoint)).Address.ToString()).ToString
```

Comment: You are querying the local IP that the `TcpListener` is listening on, not the remote IP of the client that is connecting to the `TcpListener`. `AcceptTcpClient()` returns a `TcpClient`, the client's IP is available in `TcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint`